# Windows 10 SSD 100% activity 0% transfer, so SMART problems, not superfetch

Tags: windows, ssd, freeze

I have an SSD in my computer or which normally runs as per spec, however after installing a WD 2TB blue drive my PC has started having system freezes.

Randomly my system starts having my SSD running at 100% active time, while this is happening games that are already loaded continue to run and both task manager and resource manager say that there are 0KB/s transfer rates occurring on the SSD. Thus I am unable to find out what is slowing my system.

I have run SanDisk dash board utility's advanced health check, which found no errors, or problems. I have also ran a windows disk check. I have disabled superfetch. All to no success, however when ever an event like this occurs my internet connection drops out.

When I search though the windows event log I find this
1.

```
Log Name:      System
Source:        iaStorA
Date:          7/10/2017 9:13:50 PM
Event ID:      129
Task Category: None
Level:         Warning
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      DESKTOP-07U4SST
Description:
Reset to device, \Device\RaidPort0, was issued.
Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="iaStorA" />
    <EventID Qualifiers="32772">129</EventID>
    <Level>3</Level>
    <Task>0</Task>
    <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2017-10-07T10:13:50.496008600Z" />
    <EventRecordID>3663</EventRecordID>
    <Channel>System</Channel>
    <Computer>DESKTOP-07U4SST</Computer>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data>\Device\RaidPort0</Data>
    <Binary>0F001800010000000000000081000480010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000810004800000000000000000</Binary>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

2

```
Log Name:      System
Source:        iaStorA
Date:          7/10/2017 9:14:56 PM
Event ID:      129
Task Category: None
Level:         Warning
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      DESKTOP-07U4SST
Description:
Reset to device, \Device\RaidPort0, was issued.
Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="iaStorA" />
    <EventID Qualifiers="32772">129</EventID>
    <Level>3</Level>
    <Task>0</Task>
    <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2017-10-07T10:14:56.655345500Z" />
    <EventRecordID>3664</EventRecordID>
    <Channel>System</Channel>
    <Computer>DESKTOP-07U4SST</Computer>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data>\Device\RaidPort0</Data>
    <Binary>0F001800010000000000000081000480010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000810004800000000000000000</Binary>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

3

```
Log Name:      System
Source:        e1dexpress
Date:          7/10/2017 9:17:49 PM
Event ID:      27
Task Category: None
Level:         Warning
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      DESKTOP-07U4SST
Description:
Intel(R) Ethernet Connection I217-V
 Network link is disconnected.

Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="e1dexpress" />
    <EventID Qualifiers="40964">27</EventID>
    <Level>3</Level>
    <Task>0</Task>
    <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2017-10-07T10:17:49.785166700Z" />
    <EventRecordID>3666</EventRecordID>
    <Channel>System</Channel>
    <Computer>DESKTOP-07U4SST</Computer>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data>
    </Data>
    <Data>Intel(R) Ethernet Connection I217-V</Data>
    <Binary>0000040002003000000000001B0004A00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001B0004A0</Binary>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

I don't know how to fix it. I still have warranty, but I would like to try and actually get this fixed without haven't to go months without my computer.

**Relavent Computer Parts**
Asrock b85m pro4
Intel i7-4790
WD 2TB Blue
SanDisk 250GB SSD

Comment: try to use the default Microsoft SATA drivers, not the Intel drivers

Comment: magicandre1981 When I went to update my drivers I realised that my computer is already using the generic windows drivers, which are stored under the catagory "Standard Disk Drivers", and the only microsoft driver I have is called "Microsoft Hyper-V Accelerated Disk Drive". So I am going to install and try and intel one and see if that helps, if it doesn't I'll try the microsoft one.

Comment: is it better with the Intel drivers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The AsRock b85m pro4 has two different SATA controllers, plugging the SSD into the Intel controlled port and the HDD into the other controller's port made the SSD work properly and completely to spec, however it does limit the SATA 3.0 HDD to SATA 2.0 speeds.

Comment: There are no consumer HDDs that are capped by SATA 2.0.